# Create document with REST

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-rest-api

I try to create a new document library in my subsite by via workflow.

Any one know if the SharePoint REST API can perform this action? Please guide.

I using SharePoint Online and SharePoint Designer 2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +"/_api/web/lists",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    body: "{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.List' }, 'AllowContentTypes': true, 'BaseTemplate': 101,
             'ContentTypesEnabled': true, 'Description': 'My list description', 'Title': 'Test title' }",
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
    },
    success: function (data) {

    },
    error: function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    },
});
```

Your code should be somethign like the code above, where

> 'BaseTemplate': 101,

Is the template of document library ([full list of template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listtemplatetype.aspx))

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create SharePoint Library using Rest API. Please read [this article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/472cc1/get-current-user-information-in-sharepoint-2013-rest-api455/)